# fatal: Authentication failed while pushing in repo

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a .sh file which pushes new created ODI patches to my Azure Repository, below are the contents of the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
folder_name=$(date +%s%N | cut -b1-13) &&\
cd /data/deployment/release/odi-releases &&\
shopt -s nullglob dotglob &&\
files=(/data/deployment/release/odi-releases/*.zip) &&\
if [ ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ]
then
  cd ODI-Patches && \
  git pull && \
  mkdir -p $(date +%d%m%y) &&\
  mv ../*.zip  /data/deployment/release/odi-releases/ODI-Patches/$(date +%d%m%y)/
  git add . &&\
  git commit -m "$(date +%d%m%y)" &&\
  git push -u origin master
```

Whenever a patch is created this .sh file is triggered and patch is pushed to the repo. It started failing recently with the below error :

```
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://username:token@domain.visualstudio.com/OCI/_git/ODI-Patches/'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Any document references would be helpful for future references.

Comment: Every `if` needs a closing `fi`, you are missing one.

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem. What steps have you taken to troubleshoot it and resolve it? Of course, there's also the issue of why you're storing zip files in Git; Git is not designed to hold binary files and over time your repository will become so bloated with binary data that it's unusable.